# How to make rsyslog tcpflood?

Tags: testing, rsyslog

I have setup a rsyslog-server and want to test it. I am following link [how-to-use-tcpflood](http://www.rsyslog.com/how-to-use-tcpflood/) for it.

This link says, "This tool is included in the local rsyslog folder in ‘tests’". What does it mean by local rsyslog folder? I have rsyslog (v 8.24.0-0adiscon2xenial1) installed on ubuntu machine; but it does not have any folder named "tests".

Assuming that, it might be the source code from github for rsyslog, I cloned https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog.git. The project does contain folder "tests". I run "make tcpflood" as instructed. But it fails.

```
~/rsyslog/tests$ make tcpflood
cc     tcpflood.c   -o tcpflood
tcpflood.c:86:20: fatal error: config.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'tcpflood' failed
make: *** [tcpflood] Error 1
```

What I am missing? How can I get tcpflood running?

Comment: I am also looking for the same answer, were u able to resolve the issue?

Comment: I didn't use tcpflood. Instead I used logger. Refer http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html.

Comment: For me this solution worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45346667/make-tcpflood-throws-error

Answer (score 1):

Tcpflood is a testing tool that does not exist in a package as the OP suspected. As such, a build from source needs to be done. This is described here: http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/installation/install_from_source.html

Once the initial steps are done, you can build the tcpflood tool. Obviously, it probably makes sense to create a package for this...