# make tcpflood throws error

Tags: testing, rsyslog

I am following this link ( http://www.rsyslog.com/how-to-use-tcpflood/ ) to send messages to rsyslog.

I have cloned the git repository of rsyslog  https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog.git

While following the link http://www.rsyslog.com/how-to-use-tcpflood/ , I am getting below error while  executing "make tcpflood"

```
root1@atratus06:~/Debashish/rsyslog/tests$ make tcpflood

cc     tcpflood.c   -o tcpflood
tcpflood.c:86:20: fatal error: config.h: No such file or directory
 #include "config.h"
                ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [tcpflood] Error 1
```

Can you please help me with the error, your help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Solution (or rather workaround) was to compile rsyslog...
Just go one directory up, and type:

`./configure` (you will need to probably install lot of missing stuff here...)

`make`

`make install`

After successfully completing all those actions you can go to 'tests' directory and once again type 'make tcpflood'. This time it will work.